# add setHorizontalAxisTrace to ChartPnl in java

Tags: java, cursor, jfreechart

i have program in java to paint ChartPnl using jfreechart library

i want set cursor in ChartPnl like inside this link :

http://im64.gulfup.com/gMdWqU.png

this line to determined values on chart . when i add it to chart i get values on same point

and this is my code :

```
ArrayList<ChartPnl> waveformsCharts;
 // voltage chart
    ChartPnl voltageChartPnl = new ChartPnl("VOLTAGE WAVEFORM");
    voltageChartPnl.setTimeRangeInMilli(start, end);
    voltageChartPnl.addSeries(VaTimeSeries);
    voltageChartPnl.addSeries(VbTimeSeries);
    voltageChartPnl.addSeries(VcTimeSeries);
    voltageChartPnl.setRange("V(kV)", 0.5);
    voltageChartPnl.addOptions();
    waveformsCharts.add(voltageChartPnl);
    waveformsPnl.add(voltageChartPnl.getPnl());
    voltageChartPnl.chartPnl.addChartMouseListener(this);
```

Comment: Do you want a `Marker` or a `Crosshair`?

Comment: @trashgod i want Crosshair . like picture . i want after set cursor and i get values from chart

Comment: `CrosshairDemo1` was suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711318/rendering-a-single-point-in-a-jfreechart-based-on-the-current-value-of-a-slider#comment40196790_25711318).